# how to open a menu with a button?in html

Tags: html, css, button

My question is how can i open my menu when im clicking on my button? and i want my menu to be on top
but i dont realy know how to fix it.

The point is that i want a nice functioning website for my presentation.
santino bonora,

**HTML**

```
     <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/..." />
        </head>
        <title>
            a test
        </title>
        <body>
            <button id="menubar">
                Menu
            </button>
            <ul id="menu">
                <ul>1</ul>
                <ul>2</ul>
                <ul>3</ul>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
 #menubar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(70, 100, 200);
    border: 0 none;
    font-family: consolas;
    font-size: 34px;
    height: 70px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: width 0.5s ease 0s, opacity 2s ease 0.5s;
    width: 100px;
}
#menubar:focus {
    font-family: consolas;
    font-size: 34px;
    opacity: 0.65;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1350px;
    z-index: -10;
}
#menu:hover {
    z-index: +5;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#menu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 70px;
    margin: -70px 0px 0px 100px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 1248px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgb(70,100,200);
    opacity: 0.0;
    transition: 2s ease 0s;
}
ul {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 4%;
}
```

Comment: If you make this website for you presentation, you should properly be able to do this on your own! In my opinion it would be cheating when we help you by something simple as this. If you have a concrete problem then I will be happy to help but this is just another "pls give me the code for x". Use Google, and learn how to code by reading some professional blogs / books

Comment: Where is your Js Code?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: just saw in code.. `z-index: +5;` :D LOL

Comment: a) if you just need it and don't have the time to learn from scratch, use ready made solutions, jQuery, dojo... b) a good way to present this problems and allow others to offer fast code alternatives is jsfiddle.net, just enter your code there and link it in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
#menu {
    display: none;
}

#menu:hover,
#menubar:focus + #menu {
    display: block;
}
```

This combines the `:focus` pseudo-class on the `#menubar` element with the [adjacent-sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`) to select the `#menu` element immediately following the `#menubar` element to change the `#menu` element's `display` property to "block" when the button is focussed. We also ensure that the `#menu` element remains visible when hovering so that when the focus is removed from the button the list can still be visible until the mouse leaves.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/CZL22/).

Answer (score 0):

I did a tutorial in a while to make this type of application

http://www.websourcing.com.br/2013/10/abrir-e-fechar-dropdown-com-click-e.html